# Could you be more relaxed about questions on magento stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question on magento stack exchange related to a questionnaire I would like developers to fill in.  In 30 minutes I had 3 people fill in my questionnaire and got some good feedback, then it got moved to meta and in the next 24 hours I got just one response.

I understand that my 'question' did  not fit in with the standard stack exchange question format but it seems a shame that a well received piece of information should be removed from the mainstream.  A shame for me but also a shame for others who may have wished to express their views on the state of debugging Magento.

Does magento stackexchange have to be as strict as standard stack exchange?  With the 'main' Magento Forum being down there is nowhere else for developers to raise such 'none stack exchange' type issues; sidelining them to meta will remove them from the view of many who might have been interested.

Answer (score 3):

I think the way SE works is actually correct and works well - it's good to know that if you come here you aren't going to get a whole bunch of mixed discussion and usage/development questions.  That's a good part of the attraction - you know there is a good chance you are going to be able to find an answer quickly and efficiently without wading through lots of irrelevant information.

In your particular situation, have you tried [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/) or [Mage Unity](https://mageunity.com/), there are a lot more discussion type questions there where you may have better luck with your questionnaire.

Comment: Interesting, I went on Reddit and one of the top posts is "Where do you go for online Magento Community involvement?".  Seems like there is a common need but no answer at the moment.  Mage Unity seems rather quiet, no activity for 5d.  Would +1 your help but don't have enough rep.

Comment: No worries, yeah it is pretty active here compared to some other places I think, but bear in mind also that the official Magento forums will be coming back at some point.  Not sure anybody really knows when at this point but they aren't so specific on topic so you'd be fine with something like a questionnaire I would think.